# Update Data Source and DataSet reference for SSRS 2012 Deployment from C#

Tags: c#, soap, reporting-services

EDIT: I think I can simplify this question a bit to ask for only what is needed to know:

I am working with C# using the SSRS 2010 Web Service:
'ReportService2010.asmx' http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee640743.aspx

I can use the method 'CreateDataSource' to create a Datasource on an instance of an SSRS Server http:// (servername)/ReportServer.

I can also use the method 'CreateCatalogItem' to create a report on a server from referencing a project's RDL local file to serialize it to a byte array and then pass that as a 'Definition' to the method to create it on the server.

Now everything I do works with a caveat, and a major one.  I can only deploy everything to the same folder.  If I deploy a Data Source to say the 'Data Sources' folder and then a report to say: 'Test Reports', the report does not know it has a shared data source to reference at a different location.   So I dug a little at the technet articles and have tried to 'GetItemDataSources' method but it only gives a name and a type for the ReportingService2010.DataSource return type.  **Does anyone know the method to link up a 'Report' or 'Dataset's CatalogItem property of 'DataSource', so it points to a reference in a different folder on the SSRS Server when deploying?**  There has to be a way to do it as I know I can deploy from Business Intelligence Development Studio and it can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar issues when deploying report files; when deploying through rs.exe or code you run into these issues where reports lose their link to a Data Source.

We solved this by explicitly pointing the report to the server-side Data Source immediately after being deployed by our application; is this similar to what you're trying to do?

Anyway, here's the slightly adapted code we use in our report deployment application:

```
static void SetReportDataSource(string reportPath)
    {
      string dsPath = CombinePath(DataSourcePath, DataSourceFolder, DataSourceName);

      DataSourceReference dsRef = new DataSourceReference()
      {
        Reference = dsPath
      };
      DataSource ds = new DataSource();
      ds.Item = dsRef as DataSourceDefinitionOrReference;
      ds.Name = DataSourceName;


      var rptDataSources = Server.GetItemDataSources(reportPath);
      foreach (var rptDs in rptDataSources)
      {
        Server.SetItemDataSources(filePath, new DataSource[] { ds });
      }   
    }
```

So, basically we have variables that define information like the Data Source name, Data Source location on server, and the same for a report. They can be in different folders.

Based on this, we create a new reference to a Data Source and then repoint the report to this using `SetItemDataSources`.

This sorted out the Data Source issue for me, anyway. Not sure about Shared Datasets and how they handle all of this, but hopefully this will be of some help.

Also, just thought that this would be using the `ReportService2005` endpoint, but it's probably not too different for `ReportService2010`.

**Edit:**

For the paths mentioned here, these are relative to the server, e.g. `/Reports/`. You don't need the fully qualified name as you define the `Url` property of the `ReportService2010` object which contains the destination.

Comment: Yes that appears to be exactly what I need but I am not finding the 'CombinePath' method you have after declaring an instance of the web service.  Is that a local method you use?  I am curious when you set the definition path do you just need /(folder)/(object) or do you need http://(servername)/ReportServer/(folder)/(object)?  This looks like what I want looking over your code, let me test it and see if I can get it to work for me.

Comment: I've added a bit more info about the paths. Sorry, `CombinePath` is just a private method defined somewhere else; should have been more careful with the Copying and Pasting. Unfortunately I can't run the code right now to see exactly what needs cleaning up, but hopefully it's still clear enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks I had to change your code around in parts but it works, I can't declare a new DataSource[] and get it to work for some reason, strange.  But the method works so I give you the answer.  I was curious in your coding if you have came across the fact that the 'name' of the datasource does not have to match the 'actual name' of the rds file on the server.  EG: If someone is lazy, it will just called it 'DataSource1' but it may reference 'Data Sources/TestSource'.  It appears the method of GetItemDataSources gives you the name but not the reference. Any ideas?

Comment: I found it nevermind.  If you want more detail on datasets or datasourcs you use 'GetItemReferences'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be some help. I used it to reset the DataSource for all the reports in a given Parent Folder, and it's subfolders:

```
using System;
using GetPropertiesSample.ReportService2010;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;   //<== required for LISTS
using System.Reflection;

namespace GetPropertiesSample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetListOfObjectsInGivenFolder_and_ResetTheReportDataSource("0_Contacts");  //<=== This is the parent folder
    }

    private static void GetListOfObjectsInGivenFolder_and_ResetTheReportDataSource(string sParentFolder)
    {
        // Create a Web service proxy object and set credentials
        ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        CatalogItem[] reportList = rs.ListChildren(@"/" + sParentFolder, true);

        int iCounter = 0;

        foreach (CatalogItem item in reportList)
        {
            iCounter += 1;
            Debug.Print(iCounter.ToString() + "]#########################################");

            if (item.TypeName == "Report")
            {
                Debug.Print("Report: " + item.Name);
                ResetTheDataSource_for_a_Report(item.Path, "/DataSources/Shared_New");   //<=== This is the DataSource that I want them to use
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ResetTheDataSource_for_a_Report(string sPathAndFileNameOfTheReport, string sPathAndFileNameForDataSource)
    {
        //from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144604/ssrs-reportingservice2010-change-embedded-datasource-to-shared-datasource

        ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        string reportPathAndName = sPathAndFileNameOfTheReport;
        //example of sPathAndFileNameOfTheReport  "/0_Contacts/207_Practices_County_CareManager_Role_ContactInfo";

        List<ReportService2010.ItemReference> itemRefs = new List<ReportService2010.ItemReference>();
        ReportService2010.DataSource[] itemDataSources = rs.GetItemDataSources(reportPathAndName);

        foreach (ReportService2010.DataSource itemDataSource in itemDataSources)
        {
            ReportService2010.ItemReference itemRef = new ReportService2010.ItemReference();
            itemRef.Name = itemDataSource.Name;

            //example of DataSource i.e. 'itemRef.Reference':    "/DataSources/SharedDataSource_DB2_CRM";
            itemRef.Reference = sPathAndFileNameForDataSource;

            itemRefs.Add(itemRef);
        }

        rs.SetItemReferences(reportPathAndName, itemRefs.ToArray());
    }
}
```

}